# Delphi - Automating a Website Event

Tags: delphi

I’m trying to automate the downloading of a report from a website (using a WebBrowser).

I have successfully done so for a report in the past, but now find myself having to select an entity from a dropdown list in order to generate a new table of reports for that entity.  I can change the index of the list but it will not generate the table of reports I need.

I used the “inspect” feature on Chrome to debug the code and see where the table is being generated, but my understanding of JavaScript is about 3 shades above non-existent.

It appears that when I click the option, it is firing off an “onChange” event that is not occurring when I simply choose the options (makes sense).  So, I am attempting to manually fire off this onChange event, but am admittedly getting in a little over my head with this.  It appears I need to do a bit more reading on JavaScript and probably the WebBrowser library in Delphi.

I feel like I am missing a key concept in the relationship between Delphi, HTML, and JavaScript.  I'm not even sure if I can fire off the event via Delphi (I need to find a way to emulate an event such that the Listener will pick up the entityChanged event).  I'm going in mental circles here trying to wrap my head around this and am hoping that I'm missing something very simple and basic.

My code (breaks on the Element.FireEvent, again the values I ascertained through debugging):

```
procedure TForm3.runReport;
var
  Document : IHTMLDocument2;
  Element : IHTMLElement3;
begin
  try
    Document := Form3.WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
    Element := Document.forms.item('l4iHkfgk6Nk%3D_store_11157_6%2F18%2F2014%2012%3A00%3A00%20AM',NULL) as IHTMLElement3;
    Element.FireEvent('entityChanged','Txxxxxxxxxxx (11157),l4iHkfgk6Nk=_store_11157_6/18/2014 12:00:00 AM,February 10 2017,entity');
  except
    rptSt := 1;
  end;
end;
```

Here is what I found about the Event Listener for the selection:

[image]

And here is the function that is called when I debug the event:

[image]

I apologize in advance if there is too much ambiguity in this; I tried to be as clear as possible.

Comment: I know Delphi but not IHTML*. I know JS and the code you're showing is auto-generated, judging from variable names going from "a" upwards, not to speak of inhuman constants like "!0". Why not performing a "click" on said element instead? I'd approach the whole thing in another way: record the network traffic (i.e. with *WireShark*) and then reconstruct that to download what you want.

Comment: I originally started with trying to replicate the "click". I've taken the approach of learning some web app development in Delphi and see what you're saying about that being generated code.  I will probably develop an application that emulates the site I'm trying to manipulate so I can get a better understanding of the "bones" of the whole thing.